# On glmnet lasso cox model, when to use "deviance and when to use "c"?

Tags: r, lasso, cox-model, glmnet

I am trying to use glmnet lasso cox model to select the best variables for the model using coxph, like described here https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/estimating-survival-times-with-glmnet-and-coxph-td4614225.html

My plan is to use cv.glmnet() instead of separating the data manually, get the optimum lamdba, plug back either lambda.1se or lambda.min, whatever I feel correct graphically.

I run it once with type.measure = "c", but the plot of lambda here fluctuates alot and the lamdba.1e and lamdba.min are very different.

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x, y , family = "cox" , alpha = 1, type.measure ="C")
plot(cvfit)
cvfit$lambda.1se
cvfit$lambda.min
```

```
> [1] 0.05046017
> [1] 0.002821133
```

[image: "C"]

Also tried "deviance", but I cannot really find any reference to interpret this plot. But the lambda.1se and lamdba.min is the same (yet very different from the "c" measure!)

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x, y , family = "cox" , alpha = 1, type.measure ="deviance")
plot(cvfit)
cvfit$lambda.1se
cvfit$lambda.min
```

```
> [1] 0.06077946 
> [1] 0.05046017
```

[image: Deviance]
So, what does that tells me?

I saw some analysis runs multiple cv to get optimal lambda, but I am not sure how this is working.

My plan after I settle the optimum lambda is to rerun a model this and follow the code in the reference to get HR [1](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/estimating-survival-times-with-glmnet-and-coxph-td4614225.html)

```
fit <- glmnet(x, y , family = "cox" , alpha = 1,lambda =  cvfit$lambda.1se)
```

So, tell me if you have any concerns on my analysis

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deviance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)), based on the log partial likelihood for a Cox model, is the best choice. [Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210718/28500) finds the C-index to be useful for describing a single model but not very sensitive for distinguishing among models. Your data illustrate this: the C-index values bounce around a lot over a fairly narrow range, with high standard errors, as you change the penalty factor. The deviance is much better behaved.

With your data, the outlier in terms of `lambda` values is the `lambda.min` for the C-index plot; that would give you a model maintaining ~80 predictors out of your 146 total. (The vertical dotted lines on the plots show the values for `lambda.min` and `lambda.1se` along the lower horizontal axis, with the corresponding number of maintained predictors shown along the top horizontal axis.) You might expect to find about 1 predictor maintained at `lambda.min` per 10 to 20 events, so unless you have on the order of 1000 events in your data set that outlier in terms of `lambda` values should already be raising some questions.

The C-index value for that outlier `lambda` value is very close to the C-index of a model with ~7 predictors. If you had done repeated cross-validation with different random seeds and combined results, I suspect that you would have ended up with that scale of a model instead of one with ~80 predictors. The optimum `lambda.min` from your deviance plot provides a model with ~6 predictors. So those are pretty close.

The `lambda.1se` value for the deviance criterion might seem to be close to that for the `lambda.min`, but according to your lower plot it would provide a model maintaining only ~1 predictor. There isn't much reason to use `lambda.1se` in a study like yours; it was developed as a way to get highly parsimonious models in a situation with many more predictors than cases. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/496313/28500) for a bit more on that.